# Release React-Native Android app: Could not find com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:27.1.1

Tags: android, react-native, release

When I `./gradlew assembleRelease` my React native app, I get:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:27.1.1.
```

What needs to be changed to get it right?

My build.graddle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        multiDexEnabled true // if I comment it, I run into the multidex needed error : The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
    }
}
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // commenting it does not change the problem
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `MainApplication.java`?

Answer (score 0):

If you used `react-native-navigation` then you have something like this in your *app/build.gradle*:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && requested.name != 'multidex') {
            details.useVersion "${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        }
    }
}
```

make sure to exclude also the libraries that are giving you issues in the condition above. Like so:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' 
            && requested.name != 'multidex' 
            && requested.name != 'multidex-instrumentation') {
            details.useVersion "${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        }
    }
}
```